# Is there any package or way which converts/sends data.table R code to a sql query to send to a database?

Tags: r, data.table, amazon-redshift

I want to send queries and do data maniplulation in AWS redshift from R. I use data.table in R but find that I need to do many manupulation in databases itself before bringing the data into R.

Is there a way I can pass the data.table codes to a connection inside `dBgetquery` or `dBdendUpdate` and it takes it into database and executes it?

Example:

```
library(data.table)

dBgetQuery(conn, < data.table code>)
```

Comment: As far as I know, data.table doesn't provide this functionality. This would be possible with [dbplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbplyr/vignettes/dbplyr.html)

Comment: Yes, dbplyr has one. wnated to know if data.table also has something around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to refer to this link if it will help. [Load large data to R data.table from Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328345/load-large-data-to-r-data-table-from-postgresql)
*However, dplyr package is established to be a fast and efficient for working on aws Redshift*.

```
library(dplyr)
library(RPostgreSQL)

myRedshift <- src_postgres('demo', host = 'redshiftdemo.ckffhmu2rolb.eu-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com',
port = 5439,
user = "Deb", 
password = "XXX")
```

Then, create a table reference using the function tbl(). This means you are creating an R object which points to the table in the Amazon Redshift cluster, but data is not loaded to R memory.

```
#create table reference
flights <- tbl(myRedshift, "flights")
```

refer to https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/connecting-r-with-amazon-redshift/